# Probability question of flipping coins

Tags: probability

There are $4$ coins in a box. One is a two-headed coin, there are $2$ fair coins, and the fourth is a biased coin that comes up $H$ (heads) with probability $3/4$.

If we randomly select and flip $2$ coins (without replacement), what is the
probability of getting $HH$?

So I was thinking about this question by using the normal way that dealing with each cases of probability and add them together, but there will be several cases that needed to be calculate, is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: No:  There are only three possibilities for the first (care on counting fair coin) and three for the second .  Seems easy enough.

Answer (score 2):

Let the dice be $\{D,U,F_1,F_2\}$ where $D$ is double-sided, $U$ is the unfair die, and $F_i$ are the fair dice.

Then there are $6$ ways to pick a pair of dice.

1. One way to get $\{F_1,F_2\}.$
2. Two ways to get $\{D,F_i\}.$
3. Two ways to get $\{U,F_i\}.$
4. One way to get $\{D,U\}$

The you have to compute each case separately.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'll assume that by "randomly select [and flip] 2 coins" you mean "uniformly select 2 coins". Now, naively there are $12$ possible pairs of coins to consider. However, there are only three types of coins. The outcome of $HH$ though is the same for an $xy$ pair as for a $yx$ pair, so you only need to analyse the cases $x,x$. Then you just need to correctly count the occurrences of each type combination. It shouldn't take too long. I don't think there is a very clever way to avoid a direct computation.

Comment: -1 This answer wrongly assumes the coins are selected with replacement, when the question specifically says “without replacement.”

Comment: Thanks @ThomasAndrews.